# To connect 3 LAN to a switch

Tags: cisco, switch, ethernet, layer2

I have to connect three LAN networks to a node through 24 fiber FO cable. The node contains three different networks a PLC,a security system, a CCTV network. Should I go for three separate CISCO ethernet switches or can I use one switch whcih can identify these three LANs and connect them to the users correctly

Comment: You should read up on [VLAN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_LAN)s, it's a very common technology that achieves exactly what you're desiring.

Comment: I would suggest you talk to your security people, they may have a problem with the single switch.

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 2):

you have to define 3 vlans Interface like this:

**each vlan represent a LAN(Virtual LAN)**

```
interface Vlan1
ip address 10.10.10.1 255.255.255.0 
!
interface Vlan2
ip address 20.20.20.1 255.255.255.0
!
interface Vlan3
ip address 30.30.30.1 255.255.255.0
```

and you create a vlan using:

```
vlan 2 #for example
```

then you add what ever ports you want to each vlan:

(for example):

```
interface fastethernet 0/1
switchport mode access
switchport access vlan 2
```

and so on.

Note: You have to active routing using:

```
ip routing
```

if you want a connection between the 3 LANS

Comment: I am connecting 8 nodes like the above through a ring to a central main network cabinet forming a Ehernet self healing ring network(with 24 fiber FO cable). The central main cabinet contains a switch which connects the servers for these LANs.  So the same concept is accepted for all the nodes and also the central main network cabinet containg the main switch. Which model of CISCO is best suited to form a network like above

Comment: You need to discuss this with a pre-sales engineer or in the forums as product recommendations are off topic.

Comment: @AveryAbbott, there's nothing wrong with suggesting a model in a comment; however, if a significant part of the original question is "which model should I choose?", that is off-topic.

Comment: Ok. I dont want the model no.